# force release serial port using python

Tags: c, python-2.7

python2.7  Windows 7

In a big program written by python, I called a dll using cdll.Loadlibrary to communicate with serial port. After finishing once calling, the serial port is still occupied, retarding the next calling.
I have used Process explorer and it says python.exe is occupying the serial port. How could   I force release serial port so I could call the dll to use the serial port many times in this big program written with python.

python:

```
from ctypes import *
abc_dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(r'abc.dll')
abc_dll.funtction1

......

abc_dll.funtction1
```

C:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

function1
CreateMonitorThread()
......
_exit
TerminateMonitorThread()
```

Comment: Please include a minimal snippet of code to reproduce such behaviour, otherwise it is difficult to imagine the source of your problem.

Comment: Luca`s right, you need to provide a [mcve].